# Mojolicious - can't start app with hypnotoad

Tags: perl, mojolicious

As the title says and I'm not sure why. The only thing happening is a hypnotaod.pid file appearing in the working directory. No running process, nothing listening on the defined port. Also - everything works fine with morbo.

EDIT: I've straced the startup, http://pastebin.com/YWUSeMuu

EDIT2: After looking through the strace output above it seems that hypnotad appends another ".pl" to the script file. I've change the file name to myapp, rinse, repeat http://pastebin.com/NVK2rhu4

Any ideas much appreaciated.

```
[root@fedora16 Mojo]# ./myapp.pl version
CORE
  Perl        (v5.14.2, linux)
  Mojolicious (3.02, Rainbow)

OPTIONAL
  EV              (4.11)
  IO::Socket::IP  (0.16)
  IO::Socket::SSL (1.76)

This version is up to date, have fun!

[root@fedora16 Mojo]# hypnotoad -t myapp.pl
Everything looks good!

[root@fedora16 Mojo]# hypnotoad  myapp.pl
Starting hot deployment for Hypnotoad server 29432.
```

Code by now is simply the tutorial testcode

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

app->config(hypnotoad => {listen => ['http://*:3000']});
get '/' => {text => 'ALL GLORY TO THE HYPNOTOAD!'};
app->start;
```

Comment: Have you tried 'curl localhost:3000' ?
The hypnotoad appears as 'perl' in an ps. fx. 'ps -ejH | grep perl'

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me, I removed the .pid file in the app directory and started hypnotoad again and it worked just fine!.
Hope this helps.
M.

Comment: Nearly same thing for me `Can't create process id file "/var/run/datamap/hypnotoad.pid": Can't open file "/var/run/datamap/hypnotoad.pid": No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with this as well. It was only when I happened to read the [hypnotoad](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Server/Hypnotoad) doc page closer that I saw it said "which listens on port 8080." Sure enough, opening http://127.0.0.1:8080 in my browser loaded my app.

Answer (score 1):

add `plugin 'Config';` into your application before `app->config`

If application does not load 'Config' plugin the configuration is not applyed

PS. The authors of Mojo do not beleive me that `plugin 'Config'` very implecit and not expected command when run application by hypnotoad.

**Please vote to show that it must be documented about that** **Because current DOC is too implicit to understand that**

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is try a different port (eg 3001) in case it's hitting a problem with 3000.  Then try invoking it with `MOJO_LOG_LEVEL=debug ...` to see if it gives any more info.
Ensure you have a writeable directory called 'log' and check it for output.

Comment: Port change = no effect. Log level debug with writeable 'log' dir, but no output. Again, running morbo with debug gives output.

Comment: Can you try running it in foreground `--foreground` and see if that gives anything.

Comment: Unfortunately not either; the best I have now is in the second strace output- see my edits in OP.

Comment: Couldn't load application from file "/home/sven/Development/Mojo/myapp.pl.pl": No such file or directory

Comment: There's something very wrong with your environment; I'm pretty sure it's not down to Mojolicious.  I'm also using v3.02 on linux trying to reproduce your symptoms.  I can't reproduce the bizarreness with adding '.pl' and I can't reproduce the absence of log file nor the absence of commandline messages.  What happens when you run all the tests from the Mojolicious CPAN release?  I mean against your currently installed files, not via `cpan(m)`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with tests from CPAN release? And fwiw I just tested on Centos 6.2 and it looks the same there.

Comment: Mojolicious is blessed with many unit tests, possibly more tests than code (which is how it should be).  So I'm suggesting you run everything under the `t` directory using your installed files.  (If you do it via `cpanm` it'll test the files before they're deployed, which is not what I'm suggesting.)

Comment: Unit tests won't help troubleshoot a not running webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue, with --foreground, I managed to find the a lot of warning about permission denied with user 'nobody',  after change the user parameter, the issue was fixed.

So many things can make hypnotoad fail, try to check port, file, user, group permissions etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem and every time it was related to a file permission issue.

In all cases morbo would run but hypnotoad would not.

Using the foreground flag should help you out.